# Cycle through elements of an array

Tags: ruby

I would like to cycle `@a` from `0` through `2`: `0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2`.

```
def set_a
  if @a == 2 
    @a = 0
  else
    @a = @a + 1
  end
end
```

Maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
(0..2).cycle(3) { |x| puts x } #=> 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2

item = [0, 1, 2].cycle.each

item.next #=> 0
item.next #=> 1
item.next #=> 2
item.next #=> 0
...
```

Comment: Could also be `(0..2).cycle` if the OP doesn't *need* to use an array. Also `cycle` takes an optional argument for the number of cycles.

Comment: You don't need .each to cycle through items with .next